# How to use Mailgun variable in email template?

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I am using Mailgun API with nodejs+express to send emails.
I want to transition into using templates instead of writing the whole email as the HTML tag in nodejs.

The Mailgun documentation shows how to send variables to the template but not how to use them inside the template.

This is how I'm sending the Mailgun request

```
    const data = {
    from: "Shared Video <Share@website-template.com>",
    to: shareTo,
    subject: subject,
    template: "share_video",
    v: (subject = subject),
    v: (shareToName = shareToName),
    v: (userName = userName),
    v: (videoTitle = videoTitle),
    v: (videoID = videoID),
};
mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
    req.flash("success", "Video Shared");
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

So how can I use those variables in the email template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your variables inside the template calling them as {{variable_name}}.
For example "v:video" on your post method, would just be {{video}} on the template.

Comment: Yep I got it to work check the comment on the other answer.

Yes {{variable}} does work

Answer (score -1):

According to [Mailgun Template Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templates) you can pass template data using any of the 2 options provided below,

**Option 1**

```
const data = {
  from: "Shared Video <Share@website-template.com>",
  to: shareTo,
  subject: subject,
  template: "share_video",
  'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': JSON.stringify({
    subject: subject,
    shareToName: shareToName,
    userName: userName,
    videoTitle: videoTitle,
    videoID: videoID
  })
};
```

**Option 2**

```
const data = {
  from: "Shared Video <Share@website-template.com>",
  to: shareTo,
  subject: subject,
  template: "share_video",
  'v:subject': subject,
  'v:shareToName': shareToName,
  'v:userName': userName,
  'v:videoTitle': videoTitle,
  'v:videoID': videoID,
};
```

Finally, according to their documentation

> The second way (*Option 2* in our case) is not recomended as it’s limited to simple key value
>   data. If you have arrays, dictionaries in values or complex json data
>   you have to supply variables via `X-Mailgun-Variables` header.

Comment: I solved this issue but forgot to post my own answer. and didn't clarify my question.
I ended up using something close to option 1.

My main problem was setting up the variables in the template. So I created a template using the API and found out that variables are formatted like this: `{{variable}}` in the HTML of the template.